# Ruby FileUtils mkdir_p mode - unexpected result

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the `:mode` option in `FileUtils.mkdir_p`.  However, I am getting unexpected results using Ruby 2.1.0.

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p '/this/is/my/full/path/tmp', :mode => 2750
```

Result:

```
d-wSrwxrwT  2 myuid users   4096 Mar 24 10:14 tmp
```

However, if I just call the shell commands with backticks I get the desired result:

```
`mkdir /this/is/my/full/path/tmp && chmod 2750 /this/is/my/full/path/tmp`
```

Result:

```
drwxr-s---  2 myuid users   4096 Mar 24 10:16 tmp
```

How can I create the directory with the desired permissions without using shell commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby is interpreting the permissions as an integer rather than an octal number. The chmod command (and the options passed to `mkdir_p`) takes an octal (or the equivalent as an integer). If you prepend 0 to the number, Ruby will use it as an octal.

`FileUtils.mkdir_p '/this/is/my/full/path/tmp', :mode => 02750`

Or, you could use an integer (`ruby -e 'puts 02750.to_i'` displays `1512`).

`FileUtils.mkdir_p '/this/is/my/full/path/tmp', :mode => 1512`

Comment: @GregRuhl Octal is assumed in the shell because `chmod` is manually interpreting a string, octal isn't assumed in Ruby because the four characters `2750` are converted to a Fixnum before `mkdir_p` sees the `:mode` option's value.

Answer (score 1):

this should  work, look like  method is taking permission as base 10 integer , rather  than octal (with 0 in front)

```
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.mkdir_p '/this/is/my/full/path/tmp', :mode => 02750
```

to  check permission in human readable  format this command work well for me
stat -c "%a %n" *